# $\mathbb{Z}_{22}$ surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> Show that $\mathbb{Z}_{22}$ surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I assume that we should use isomorphism theorems here or maybe quotients maps?

I tried finding homomorphism for the first isomorphism theorem but I couldn't find any...

And ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove directly that $x \bmod 22 \mapsto x \bmod 2$ is a well-defined surjective homomorphism.

More generally, if $d$ divides $n$, then $x \bmod n \mapsto x \bmod d$ is a well-defined surjective homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \to \mathbb{Z}_{d}$.

Answer (score 2):

You want exactly half of the elements of the domain in the kernel of your map. Think about the parity of the elements.

Comment: So we could define homomorphism that takes even numbers to $0$ and odd numbers to $1$?

Comment: That's a great idea!

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out how you can create a surjective homomorphism. But 
$$
 \textbf{if} 
$$
you are just looking for a function from $\mathbb{Z}_{22} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$, you could create any function you wanted. For example
$$
f(x) =\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x = 0 \\
1& \text{if } x\neq 0
\end{cases}
$$
will be a surjective function.

Comment: Yes of course, but I needed it to be home homomorphism as well.

Comment: @ChikChak: Ok, I wasn't sure based on your question.